# How do you write a cmake.yml which allows you to review a file on GitHub?

Tags: github, cmake, file-io, yaml, github-actions

I have written a program which takes in an single command line argument containing the input file, and runs it through some algorithms and creating a txtfile containing the results.

What I need to be able to do is review the file using GitHub Actions. My program builds with GitHub Actions, I just can't review the output files.

Currently this is how I have my cmake.yml set up:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

env:
  BUILD_TYPE: Debug
  file's
  TEST_EXE: 22s_pa01_nicandpaige
  INPUT_FILE: input/input.txt
  OUTPUT_FILE: output/test-highvalue.txt output/test-custom.txt. output/test-bruteforce



jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 3

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure CMake
        run: cmake -B ${{github.workspace}}/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}

      - name: Build
        run: cmake --build ${{github.workspace}}/build --config ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}


      - name: Execute Project
        working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/build
        run: ${{github.workspace}}/build/${{env.TEST_EXE}} ${{env.INPUT_FILE}} ${{env.OUTPUT_FILE}}

      - name: Upload output files to GitHub so they can be reviewed
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: project_output
          path: ${{github.workspace}}/build/output
```

And with regards to how I have written the textfiles within my program:

```
std:: ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("../output/test-highvalue.txt");
    for (auto & i : x){
        myfile << i.getId();
        myfile << " ";
        myfile << i.getValue();
        totalValue += i.getValue();
        myfile << " ";
        myfile << i.getLength();
        myfile << " ";
        myfile << i.getH();
        myfile << std:: endl;
    }
```

The following code above is replicated cross three different classes and gets called in main.

As for how we have called for the input file:

```
std::vector<paintingData> read_paintings(char* arg){
    std::ifstream inFS(arg);
    if(!inFS.is_open()){
        std::cout << "Failed to open " << arg << std::endl;
        return std::vector<paintingData>();
    }
```

This function is more extensive than this, but it gets called in main, and the data gets passed to the necessary algorithms.

Although it is building, when I review the build closer I get the following messages

> Please execute this program with the input file name included as an argument.

and

> Warning: No files were found with the provided path: /home/runner/work/22s-pa01-nicandpaige/22s-pa01-nicandpaige/build/output. No artifacts will be uploaded.

I am not to sure where exactly the problem lies as this is my first time writing a cmake.yml, and I have hit a block.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your yaml file is syntactically correct? I was stumbling over the "file's" line that is IMHO not valid yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an error message emitted by your program:

> Please execute this program with the input file name included as an argument.

We can't know what goes wrong because you don't show the part of your program that emits this.

You say

> I have written a program which takes in an single command line argument

but you give multiple arguments:

```
${{env.INPUT_FILE}} ${{env.OUTPUT_FILE}}
```

You show the code line

```
myfile.open ("../output/test-highvalue.txt");
```

your working directory is `${{github.workspace}}/build`, therefore your output directory is `${{github.workspace}}/output`, not `${{github.workspace}}/build/output`.

You don't show how you create the `output` directory.

To sum up: There are some fishy things but you don't give enough information for us to actually figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I will edit this post to include that information.

Comment: Upon further inspection, your comment about the directory seemed to be the issue. This problem is now resolved